# How can i change fill color of a vector file fetched from server in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, svg, android-vectordrawable

Is there anyway I can access the elements of vector file like fill color on the click of certain path fetched from the server. I am fetching whole vector file from the server. I have tried many library including [RichPath](https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath) ,[VectorChildFinder](https://github.com/devendroid/VectorChildFinder), [AndroidSVG](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg) but they require a vector file which is stored in res folder. It would not feasible to keep all the files in the res folder as there are many.
What I have achieved is I can parse it into a imageview but can't access the elements inside it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the others, but AndroidSVG does not require the file to be in a res or assets folder.  The library doesn't include any method to fetch from a URL, but you can always fetch the file yourself and then use `SVG.getFromString(fetchedSVGData)`.

If you don't want to handle the fetching yourself, you could use a library like Glide.  It has an [example of how to fetch SVGs and display with AndroidSVG](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/samples/svg).

To colour the SVG, just use AndroidSVGs ability to pass CSS stylesheet when rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i also want to keep the elements inside the file clickable. I am working on a meeting room booking app where i want to show the floorplan(which is a svg file coming from server) to user so that the user can select the chairs and change the color of the chair on  selection.